# Why does COMP_WORDBREAKS exists? What are usefull cases for using COMP_WORDBREAKS?

Tags: bash, readline, bash-completion, completion

Many confused programmers stumbled upon COMP_WORDBREAKS. The documentation states https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html :

> COMP_WORDBREAKS
>
> The set of characters that the Readline library treats as word separators when performing word completion. If COMP_WORDBREAKS is unset, it loses its special properties, even if it is subsequently reset.

On my system:

```
$ declare -p COMP_WORDBREAKS
declare -- COMP_WORDBREAKS=$' \t\n"\'><=;|&(:'
```

Why and when if ever is COMP_WORDBREAKS ever useful? Why was it invented, and what is the point of it? Why would ever `:` or `=` be breaking words and how did those characters end up there?

I tried browsing the net, but it only resulted in finding out about more confused programmers. The bash changelog just states "COMP_WORDBREAKS now exists" https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/2bb3cbefdb8fd019765b1a9cc42ecf37ff22fec6/NEWS#L1488 . I was not able to find the reason why COMP_WORDBREAKS exists in the first place.

The question originates because every bash completion function I know of has to *workaround* COMP_WORDBREAKS by joining the words from CWORD back after COMP_WORDBREAKS has split them. Commonly `_comp_get_words` or now deprecated `__get_cword_at_cursor_by_ref` and `__reassemble_comp_words_by_ref` from [bash-completion project](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion) are used to workaround COMP_WORDBREAKS. Or, alternatively, COMP_WORDBREAKS is very useful and used in specific contexts when writing bash completion. If so, in which contexts and how is it used?

In contrast, `zsh` does not have COMP_WORDBREAKS, instead you can execute `compset` *locally* from the completion function. What usefulness does COMP_WORDBREAKS brings if it is being set for *all* completion functions within Bash?

Comment: This looks more suitable for [unix.se] instead. It's not programming-related, and is more of an OS/shell question than anything else. I'd suspect you'll get an answer there more quickly as well.

Comment: The description seems self-explanatory. When you're doing word completion, it needs to know where the words begin and end. This variable defines that.

Comment: `ls --color=` ? `rsync host:` ?

Comment: @KenWhite Hi, thanks. I disagree, thus the question. I am asking about programming bash completion, and in that context, how or in what way is COMP_WORDBREAKS useful when programming that completion. It seems nothing but trouble - if so, what utilities does COMP_WORDBREAKS bring to the programmer. Also, I am asking specifically about bash and readline softwares, not about linux in general. Thanks.

Comment: @Barmar Words do not begin or end on : and =. Why these characters there?

Comment: @jhnc Hi, I agree, exactly. In bash-completion project, rsync uses `_comp_initialize -s -n :` which specifically is designed to _workaround_ COMP_WORDBREAK with colon. Additionally, `_comp_initialize` works around `<` `>` `&` being in COMP_WORDBREAK [here](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/de15205d6c7997e8596dce4f9d2a2bfc476be716/bash_completion#L1362). In case of `ls`, `_comp_compgen_split` has to handle `=`. Great examples, they _show_ that COMP_WORDBREAK is in the way. If so, why does it exist, and when is it useful?  Or is it used actually? If so, where and how?

Comment: You're asking about a *nix command line utility. It's not a specific question about code in a bash script, which means it's an OS-related question and not a programming question. This would have been acceptable to ask here in the days before [unix.se] and [ubuntu.se] existed - they're here now, and this sort of question should be asked there instead.

Comment: @KamilCuk : maybe you can put your last comment in the body of the question and structure it as a [mcve] ? An interesting issue, but as is, I agree that you're asking about how to use `find` or someother utility.

Comment: If you write `foo:bar` it's two words, the `:` separates the end of the first word from the beginning of the second word. And if you type the completion character after this, it will just try to complete `foo`.

Comment: And if you write `var=value` that has meaning as 2 words as well. AND  actually, that "list" (`$' \t\n"\'><=;|&(:'`) chimes very closely to the way some Xwindows managers dbl-click-on-a-word feature would decide where your words ended. Maybe that is why it is used?